# Why is .textContent in an "if statement" not considered while code is running?

Tags: javascript, html

The `.textContent` in the `if statements` is not considered while code is running? Is there a way to make it Work? Simplified version of the code is below, where the goal is:
`A` should be followed by `b` and
`B` should be followed by `c`

```js
function F1() {

  var Vt1 = [
    'A',
    'B',
  ];

  t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
  t2 = document.getElementById("t2");

  vt1 = Vt1[Math.floor(Math.random() * Vt1.length)];

  t1.innerHTML = vt1;

  if (t1 === 'A') {
    t2.textContent = "b";
  }

  if (t1 === 'B') {
    t2.textContent = "c";
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()" class="button"> New </button>
<label id="t1"> </label> <label id="t2"> </label>
```

Comment: `t1` is a HTMLElement. I assume you mean `vt1` in your `if` statements; eg. `if (t1 === "A") {...` becomes `if (vt1 === "A") {...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write

```
if (t1.textContent  === 'A')
```

same for t2 also

because

```
t1 = document.getElementById("t1")
```

it returns HTML element only
if you need text inside you can use

```
t1 = document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML
```

Now you can use t1 directly